# Working with Large Datasets in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am looking for some advice, we are creating a website tracking platform (like Google Analytics) and are going to be working with 1,000,000's of rows of data. What is the best way to work with this within MySQL?

I will be tracking website visitors, so a website could have 20/30k visits a day and these will all be saved in the database. Once we get to 1 year we could be looking at over 11m rows and that's just one account. Would it be best to create a database table per website? And move the data to a secondary table for that website after 1 year? Or is there a better way of doing it?

**To Add Some Additional Context to This**

When a user visits a website the tracking software will get the user information and the page visited and save it into the database.

This user information will be saved against the website ID and will house around 5-6 different items like browser, IP address, Time on site etc...

There are 2 ways in which I can see to do this;

1. Save the data into a visits table for each website so when a new website is added it will be called WEBSITEID_visits etc...
2. Save the data into a visits table for each month, using a website Id to be able to reference which website it relates to.

Is there a better way to do this, also should I use something different to MySQL?

Sorry if this isn't the right place to post this.

Comment: Too broad. There are too few specifics and the topic is a bit too large and detailed to really put it into an SO answer imo.

Comment: I have tried to expand above.

Comment: Books have been written on how to build and maintain a data warehouse.  Find one or two of those books and read them cover to cover.

Comment: Ok thank you, ill read a book!

Comment: Without knowing what you want from the data it is hard to say how to structure the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One row ever few seconds is a rather low rate for Data Warehousing.  Here are some tips.

- Normalize!  Look at the columns, decide which ones have a lot of repetition (browser, user, etc).  Build normalization tables for them, and store their ids into the "Fact" table.  Do not normalize any "continuous" values, such as datetime.
- Do not use multiple tables based on time.  It will complicate your code without providing benefits.
- Do not `PARTITION` the Fact table unless your use case matches one of the four mentioned [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/) .
- [*Summarize*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/) the data.  Running `COUNT(*)` or `SUM(...)` over a month's worth of data will be painfully slow.